# Mobile safari & iOS 11 : Web apps and full height (100vh) overlapped by nav bar

Tags: css, web-applications, responsive-design, mobile-safari

Using 100vh on Mobile Safari does not take into consideration the height of the lower navigation bar.

Take the example screenshot below. In order to display my app-like footer, I need to manually (and in an ugly manner ,see code below) subtract 74px from the container's height. Not doing so simply hides my footer under the navigation footer of mobile Safari.

Is there a common&clean way to work around this?

[image]

I fix this using the following code. It's ugly to me. User-agent deduced platform/browser and hard-coded offset to get rid of a native behavior. Trusting my solution doesn't feel good:

**edit** btw this code runs in the ngAfterViewInit() method of my Angular4 "responsive, mobile first and progressive web app" (buzwords power)

```
const wrapper:any = document.getElementsByClassName('hack-to-fix-ios-height')[0];
if(wrapper && this.iOS()){
  let height = wrapper.offsetHeight;
  height -= 74;

  // Mobile Safari fix for footer nav
  this.renderer.setStyle(wrapper, 'height', height + 'px');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting wrapper.style.height to window.innerHeight. I believe that will give you the height without the navbar - if the navbar is visible. If your user scrolls down and makes the navbar disappear. Then window.innerHeight will increase by the height of the navbar.